# WDS Capture Image Failing to Load

Tags: wds

Using the instructions posted here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11680.creating-a-capture-image-in-wds.aspx I created a capture image and then injected network drivers into the boot image. When trying to load the capture image I get the error:

Status: 0x000000f
Info: The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.

Does anyone know what might cause this or how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you add storage drivers to the image also?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're having the same issue that I did, but I found this [link](http://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/values-for-the-start-registry-entry.html) on driver start values (the whole tutorial is super useful for understanding the Windows start up process).  Due to some idiosyncrasies of the image creation process the drivers for the hard drive weren't being loaded at the wrong time.

What I had to do was:

1. Start up the computer in WinPE
2. Use regedit to load the offline system registry hive (you may have to add regedit to WinPE)
3. Find the drivers for the hard drive and change their start value

Each of those steps is a project unto itself, but it worked!

Comment: If you do the above, you may have additional issues that may be addressed [here](http://superuser.com/questions/425629/can-not-install-wim-onto-a-dell-using-windows-pe/425749#425749)